# KeystoneJS: How can I populate data in a populated element?

Tags: javascript, mongoose, keystonejs

I have a page, and it has collections added to it. Inside those collections are more elements. How do I populate both the collection and the elements inside it.

3 models:

Page

```
Page.add({
    title: { type: String, initial: true, required: true},
    collections: { type: Types.Relationship, ref: 'Collection', many: true, sortable: true}
});
```

Collection

```
Collection.add({
    title: { type: String, initial: true, required: true},
    elements: { type: Types.Relationship, ref: 'Element', many: true, sortable: true}
});
```

Element

```
Element.add({
    title: { type: String, initial: true, required: true}
});
```

and I'm trying to load them...

```
view.on('init', function(next) {

    var q = keystone.list('page').model.findOne({
        state: 'published',
        }).populate('collections collections[*].elements');

    q.exec(function(err, result) {
        if (result !== null) {
            locals.data.page = result;
        }else{
            return res.status(404).render('errors/404')
        }
    });

});
```

I think I could do it something like this...

```
var async = require('async');

view.on('init', function(next) {

    var q = keystone.list('page').model.findOne({
        state: 'published',
        });

    q.exec(function(err, result) {
        locals.data.page = result;

        var cl = locals.data.page.collections;
        async.forEachOf( cl, function(collection, i, callback){
            keystone.list('Collection').model.findById(collection).populate('elements').exec(function(err, elements) {

                cl = locals.data.page.collections;
                if (collection !== null) {

                    cl[i] = elements;       
                    callback();
                }
            });
        }, function(err){
            next(err)
        });
    }
});
```

But there must be a better way.

Answer (score 0):

You can try deep populating something like below code

```
var q = keystone.list('page').model.findOne({
    state: 'published',
    }).populate({path: 'collections', populate: ['element']});

q.exec(function(err, result) {
    if (result !== null) {
        locals.data.page = result;
    }else{
        return res.status(404).render('errors/404')
    }
});
```